# I need math help in calculating the variance, to find variance when given range and mean

Tags: probability, statistics, variance

x is a random variable with range (2,3), mean=9/4 what is the variance? I need to know if what the variance is by only having the mean and range. Please help

Comment: which is the distribution of $x$?

Comment: These are the only details, the question goes as follows: x is a random variable with range consisting of {2,3}, mean=9/4. Find the variance.

Comment: yes, i think so

Comment: @integratethis a continuous uniform distribution has mean in the center, which would be 5/2 (fixed typo.. point was its not 9/4), so there seems to be a problem here.

Comment: @Mark you are right. I guess op meant the probabilities are not known for the two values, but you are given $X = \{2, 3\}$ , not a "range", and the mean is $9/4$.

Answer (score 2):

You know $1 = p_2 + p_3$ and $9/4 = 2 p_2 + 3 p_3$, so you can figure out that $p_2 = 3/4$. Then it's a matter of computing the variance as
$(2 - 9/4)^2p_2 + (3 - 9/4)^2p_3$.

Comment: so the answer is 5/8, however in my book it says its 3/16

Comment: The answer is $3/16$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you go over it again

Comment: $(-1/4)^2(3/4) + (3/4)^2(1/4) ...$

Comment: thank you so much @aruralreader